# How to delete last character Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, numbers

Hi I have a list of data that I was preparing to import as a 'Number'

However the data I recieved had a String at the end of the number.

Example: 350 M, 25 M

How should I delete the character 'M' and maybe any empty space.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTR(column, 0, length(column)-1) 
WHERE SUBSTR(column, -1, 1) = 'M';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine the `SUBSTR` and `LENGTH` functions like this:

```
select SUBSTR('350 M', 0, LENGTH('350 M') - 1) from dual;
```

(or -2 if you want to remove the space also)

Comment: Just want to point out that plsql strings start with index 1 not 0.
SubStr('123', 0, 2) and SubStr('123', 1, 2) leads to the same result '12'

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get exactly the number, so I think it is easier to do with a regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr('350 M','^[0-9]+')
from dual;
```

Maybe it does not answer your current question but should solve your problem on another level.